# Is it possible to write a program in C which is able to set the MSL for a UDP-Packet?

Tags: c, udp

Is it possible to write a program in C which is able to set the MSL for a UDP-Packet and receive the return information of the death, so I can get the information where the package was? I read that you can only set it in the OS but how is it possible that programs like traceroute use exactly this headeroption from UDP?

Comment: Yes but you would be dealing with raw sockets and would have to construct the entire IP and UDP headers yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the time to live (TTL)? You should be able to use the `IP_TTL` socket option (see ip(7)) to set the time to live of packets sent on that socket. If the packet goes through enough hops for the TTL to become zero, the node that discards the packet should send an ICMP Time Exceeded message back to the originating host. To receive the error, I think you might have to create an ICMP socket. This is what `traceroute` does, so you might want to take a look at the source code.

Comment: I think I was talking about this.